# How can render a curved border for a parent that stays on top of a child?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

> I want a inside curved border on a View, that stays on top even when I add/swap/remove children to/inside/from it.

Here's what I have tried:

- Created an `XML resource` for the black border (with inside curved border)
- Set it as the `background` of Parent `FrameLayout`
- Added `Fragment` with `ImageView` to the `FrameLayout`
- I'm *not* doing this on `ImageView` bcoz this `Fragment` will be swapped during runtime, with fragments of different color, and they should **slide under** the black border rather than *sliding over* it.

> The children are always drawn over the parent!

[image]

> And here's what I expect

[image]

[image]

XML Resource file (for inside curved border)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#ff000000" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

> Is there a way to do this without having a `RelativeLayout`inside which we can have two separate children, one for border and the other for imageView?

Comment: override `draw` / `dispatchDraw` of your parent view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like [pskink mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291240/how-can-render-a-curved-border-for-a-parent-that-stays-on-top-of-a-child#comment65916244_39291240) you can easily achieve that by overriding `draw` or `dispatchDraw` in your `ViewGroup`.

What you have to do is:

1. Remove `background` drawable from your `FrameLayout`
2. Instead of a regular `FrameLayout` use something like this:

```
public class RoundedBorderFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    // ... constructors and setting up Paint and Rect objects (for drawing)

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas); // AFTER super call!!
        //... draw black rounded border on Canvas object
    }
}
```

Comment: is this called everytime its children gets rendered?

Comment: @ZekeDran `super.draw(canvas)` draws (renders) the children